# restrict `apt upgrade` to available hardware or hardware version

Tags: hardware, update

I have an old-ish RPi 1BP. It's slow, but remains useful for some things. I do keep the software current through periodic `apt update` & `apt upgrade`.

I've noticed that since the upgrade to **buster**, the `upgrade` process has become lengthy, typically requiring several minutes (occasionally 10-15 minutes) to complete. The 1BP is old, it's slow and the `eth0` bandwidth is limited - I understand that. However, needless downloads of packages such as `rpi-eeprom`, `bluez`, bluetooth, wifi drivers, etc. requires additional time for download and processing. Some - e.g. the `rpi-eeprom` package - are later deleted.

I've read the "official" documentation on [Updating and Upgrading](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md), and searched for methods to perform **hardware version dependent** upgrades, but nothing has turned up. Does anyone know of a way to limit the `upgrade` (or `update`) process to only the packages relevant to that hardware version?

Comment: Not tested but maybe one way to do it: set the "Pin-Priority" less than zero for each unwanted package: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html . I agree, there should be a better option unless you want to blacklist just a few packages :-)